# Como mapear uma entidade com chave composta utilizando JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "USUARIO")

public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "USER_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String userName;
}

@Entity

@Table(name = "CARGO")

public class Cargo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;
}

@Entity

@Table(name = "USUARIO_CARGO")

public class Cargo implements Serializable {

    @JoinColumn(name = "USARIO_ID")
    private User user;

    @JoinColumn(name = "CARGO_ID")
    private Cargo cargo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cara não sei se é isso que vc quer mas esta ai

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USUARIO_CARGO")
public class usuario_Cargo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "USARIO_ID", referencedColumnName= "id")
    private User user;

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "CARGO_ID", referencedColumnName= "id")
    private Cargo cargo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

eu uso exatamente assim e funciona.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USUARIO_CARGO")
public class usuario_Cargo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USARIO_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private User user;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CARGO_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private Cargo cargo;

}
```

Veja se resolve...

Answer (score 0):

Pra mim, usuario_cargo é um JOIN TABLE, não deveria se tornar uma entidade, você pode mapear direto em usuario ou cargo, no exemplo, como se fosse em usuario:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
  name = "USUARIO_CARGO", 
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USARIO_ID"), 
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CARGO_ID"))
List<Cargo> cargos;
```